# Unable to start Unicorn server in capistrano 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-ec2, unicorn, capistrano3

This is my config/unicorn/development.rb

```
app_path = "/home/ec2-user/apps/app_dev/current"

worker_processes 1
preload_app false
timeout 300
listen 3333

working_directory app_path
pid "#{app_path}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"

rails_env = 'development'

stderr_path "log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "log/unicorn.log"
```

This my Capfile

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Includes default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'


require 'capistrano/rvm'
# require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
# require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano3/unicorn'
# require 'sidekiq/capistrano'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

while running the following command `"cap development unicorn:start"` from my local environment

i am getting the following error

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
DEBUG [eba94152]    
DEBUG [eba94152]    You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
DEBUG [eba94152]    Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
DEBUG [eba94152]    Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
DEBUG [eba94152]    
DEBUG [eba94152]    /home/ec2-user/apps/app_dev/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:75:in `read'
DEBUG [eba94152]    : 
DEBUG [eba94152]    No such file or directory - /home/ec2-user/apps/app_dev/current/config/unicorn/.rb
DEBUG [eba94152]     (
DEBUG [eba94152]    Errno::ENOENT
DEBUG [eba94152]    )
cap aborted!
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: Nothing written
```

Let me know how to start the unicorn server in master branch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the following line:

> No such file or directory - /home/ec2-user/apps/app_dev/current/config/unicorn/.rb

I gather that unicorn is looking for `/home/ec2-user/apps/app_dev/current/config/unicorn/<something should be here>.rb`. This "something should be here", I expect is 'development' which I guess it is trying to take from `fetch(:stage)`.

Try adding to `development.rb`

```
set :stage, :development
```

**Edit**

I did not notice the circularity of the logic of what I suggested (add something to the file that was not found to show where it is...) - you should add this line to `config/deploy/development.rb`, not to `config/unicorn/development.rb`... :-P

**Update**

Since that did not work, I've dug a bit in `capistrano3/unicorn` [code](https://github.com/tablexi/capistrano3-unicorn/blob/master/lib/capistrano3/tasks/unicorn.rake#L4), and found that the environment variable it is looking for is `:rails_env`, so also add

```
set :rails_env, :development
```

Comment: Yes it's already there in config/deploy/development.rb. but doesn't worked.

Comment: i am starting the server from local machine.it just says that unicorn is running and when i check with ps -ef|grep unicorn in remote machine. it says that it running in deployment -D and not development -D. i don't see any changes in GUI. Do let me know what to do.

Comment: Apparently this is by design(https://github.com/tablexi/capistrano3-unicorn/blob/master/lib/capistrano3/tasks/unicorn.rake#L8) - when you run in development, it passes `-E deployment` (I don't know why, but they went to great lengths to implement that, so it is not a mistake...)

Comment: I have added set :rails_env, :development in config/unicorn/development.rb

Comment: Yes, when you do that, it will run `exec unicorn -c development -E deployment -D ...`. The `-c` tells it what is the config file name...

Comment: when i run cap development deploy from local machine, tmp/pids folder in the apps/current folder get lost. please let me know what should i do to prevent loss of tmp/pids folder to recreate the these folders? Thanks in advance

Comment: You could open another question on this subject. Anyway, make sure that `tmp/pids` is in your `:linked_list` - `set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49148/discussion-between-krs-and-uri-agassi)

Comment: -I can't start Unicorn which runs on 80 by cap production unicorn:start please do check this link http://pastebin.com/AHXZV2QK for my tail-f log/unicorn.log.

Comment: Please open another question for this, and make sure that you give the _whole_ exception trace in it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318802/unable-to-start-my-unicorn-on-port-80-on-capistrano-3