# Unable to start my Unicorn on Port 80 on Capistrano 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn, capistrano3

I get the following error while trying to run

### "cap production unicorn:start"

```
DEBUG [29ec5890] Command: cd /home/ec2-user/apps/current && ( RAILS_ENV=production BUNDLE_GEMFILE=/home/ec2-user/apps/current/Gemfile ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec unicorn -c /home/ec2-user/apps/current/config/unicorn/production.rb -E deployment -D  )
DEBUG [29ec5890]    RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
DEBUG [29ec5890]    
DEBUG [29ec5890]    You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
DEBUG [29ec5890]    Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
DEBUG [29ec5890]    Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
DEBUG [29ec5890]    
DEBUG [29ec5890]    master failed to start, check stderr log for details
cap aborted!
bundle stdout: Nothing written
```

### tail -f log/unicorn.log

```
from /home/ec2-user/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:185:in `new_tcp_server'
    from /home/ec2-user/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:165:in `bind_listen'
    from /home/ec2-user/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:242:in `listen'
    from /home/ec2-user/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:805:in `block in bind_new_listeners!'
    from /home/ec2-user/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:805:in `each'
    from /home/ec2-user/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:805:in `bind_new_listeners!'
    from /home/ec2-user/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:138:in `start'
    from /home/ec2-user/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ec2-user/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
    from /home/ec2-user/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

What should be configured to start the unicorn in port 80. Thanks in advance

Comment: That's the stack trace, without the exception!

Comment: so, what should i do to start the unicorn with "cap production unicorn:start" command. please do let me know

Comment: Please paste a few more lines from the log - there is not enough information

Comment: I am not familiar with this but can you try running it with higher permission? I believe you need an escalated permission to use the port 80. Anyways, that is just an idea. I am not familiar with unicorn or capistrano.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try following the advice on this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15629654/1120015):</strike>

> In my deploy.rb file, setting this line:
>
> ```
> set :bundle_dir, "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-X.X.X-pXXX"
> ```
>
> before this line:
>
> ```
> require 'bundler/capistrano'
> ```
>
> seemed to help bundler know where to install the gems. Not sure why
>   this is needed. I've never needed it before.

**EDIT**

On capistrano3, if you are using gem `rvm1-capistrano3`, you might need to update it, as it is a [fixed issue](https://github.com/rvm/rvm1-capistrano3/issues/8):

```
bundle update rvm1-capistrano3
```

Also, you should use the [capistrano3 fork](https://github.com/sepastian/capistrano-unicorn) of `capistrano-unicorn`:

> Add the library to your Gemfile:
>
> ```
> group :development do
>   gem 'sepastian-capistrano3-unicorn', :require => false
> end
> ```

... and remove the line

```
 gem 'capistrano3-unicorn'
```

Comment: I am using Capistrano-3. The above answer won't for it. and i need to start my unicorn at port 80 as well.

Comment: try changing you unicorn gem (see my updated answer)

Comment: could you paste your Gemfile?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49660/discussion-between-uri-agassi-and-krs)